# Matlab sum: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, sum, symbolic-math

When I try to run this code, this error message keeps showing up in matlab:

> The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target
>   for an assignment.

`a_k` and `b_k` are meant to be row vectors of size `(1,m)`. I can't use the command `symsum` because it doesn't let me index these vectors within the `symsum`. The resulting sum has to involve the `dirac` and `heaviside` functions. Ideas? :)

```
prompt = 'Enter m';
m = input(prompt);
prompt = 'Enter x-coordinates of dislocations';
a_k = input(prompt);
prompt = 'Enter y-coordinates of dislocations';
b_k = input(prompt);

syms x_1 x_2 y_1 y_2

F_1(y_1,y_2) = sum(heaviside(y_1-a_k(1,i))*dirac(1,y_2-b_k(1,i)), i=1:m);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an invalid `sum` syntax, i.e. `i=1:m`.

[`sum`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) calculates the sum of all the elements in an array. So, you need to rewrite your formula in vectorised way using elementwise operations as follows:

```
F_1(y_1, y_2) = sum(heaviside(y_1-a_k(1,1:m)).*dirac(1,y_2-b_k(1,1:m)));
```